# msxml4 parseError undefined?

Tags: msxml

I have a Classic ASP website that uses a DLL to create a Msxml2.DOMDocument object and returns that to the browser (called from an jQuery ajax call). I run the website on two computers. Both have the same classic ASP, and both have the same version of the DLL file registered.

Under one environment the returned XML object has a "parseError" property, and has an "xml" property that contains a string representation of the XMl in the object. The object type of the XML returned by the server is IXMLDOMDocument2 (as viewed in the browser's debugging tools).

But in my second environment the returned object seems to be of type "XMLDocument", and it doesn't have the "parseError" or "xml" properties.

In both environments, Windows shows that MSXML4 SP2 is installed in "Programs and Features", but only versions 3.0 and 6.0 are listed in this registry key:
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{2933BF90-7B36-11D2-B20E-00C04F983E60}\VersionList

Both environments have identical ASP code, and I've registered the same DLL file, which generates the XML to return, in both environments.

What might cause one environment to return a different XML object under the same conditions?

I'm not sure where to begin to solve this.

Comment: What about the browser versions?

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Compatibility Mode (Internet Explorer) being enabled in one environment but not the other was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue, it was silly. The website in question is very old, and most of the pages don't work unless you have IE's Compatibility Mode enabled. Compatibility Mode was enabled in IE for the environment which worked as I expected (it returns an IXMLDOMDocument2 object), but it was not enabled in the other environment.